# Meaning of それは構わないんだけどね

Tags: meaning

> 「おはよう、有地君』
>
> 「朝早くからすみません」
>
> 『**それは構わないんだけどね**』
>
> 『わざわざこんな時間に連絡をくれるなんて、なにか問題が？』

Why was んだけどね added onto the end of the sentence above?

I guess my question is really, why is it それは構わないんだけどね instead of それは構わないわ or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [んですが and differences in nuance with んです](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33093/%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c-and-differences-in-nuance-with-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99)

Answer (score 3):

けど adds the feeling of "but..." to the sentence. Sentence-end けど/が/etc is fairly common in Japanese. See: [けど at the end of the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2086/5010)

In this context, this "but" makes the sentence naturally connect to the following line. He says contacting him early in the morning itself does not matter, **but** he is worried if there is some problem that actually matters.

> "It's okay, **but...**"
>   "...contacting me at this time in the morning — so you've got some problem?"